# Can i let a for n in range keep going despite item

Tags: python

I relatively new to coding, so I need a bit of help figuring this out.

I'm creating a game using pygame, and I have a for n in range loop that sorts through the characters  'frames' for the animations. The issue I'm having here is that the players' death animation is 11 frames while the enemy is only 4 frames when loading the enemy's death animation. So the for loop fails due to it not finding more frames. I was wondering if there was a way to potentially make it ignore the fact that there are no more frames or another solution, perhaps. I'll put the piece of code below. Thank you.

```
tempList = []
    for n in range(11):
        img = pygame.image.load(
            f'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Game\\Imgs\\Sprites\\{self.name}\\Dead\\tile{n}.png')
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (img.get_width() * 2.5, img.get_width() * 2.5))
        tempList.append(img)
    self.animationList.append(tempList)
```

Comment: you could use a ```try``` and an ```except``` statement and ```break``` when there is an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the os module to check if the file exists before loading/transforming throws an error with a file that isn't there.

```
from os.path import exists


tempList = []
    for n in range(11):
        filename = f'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Game\\Imgs\\Sprites\\{self.name}\\Dead\\tile{n}.png'
        if os.path.exists(filename) is False:
            continue 
        img = pygame.image.load(filename)
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (img.get_width() * 2.5, img.get_width() * 2.5))
        tempList.append(img)
    self.animationList.append(tempList)
```

Comment: it is more pythonic to do ```if not os.path.exists(filename):```,  [pep8 programming recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)